# In-App Purchase working or not when remove my account from iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am using auto renewal subscription In-App Purchase in my application. I want to know what happened when i remove my apple account after purchase in iPhone. in app purchase is worked or not ?? I am using sandbox environment.

If not so how to know in-app apple account was removed ??

I have try to  verifying the receipt and checked the in-app purchased is expire or not, but after remove apple account i  always get receipt response true.

here is my get receipt request code :

```
@objc func loadreceipt() {
        if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
            FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {
            if UD.getS(receiptdata).isEmpty == false {
                Api.inAppPurchasecall(.receiptVarify(rdata: UD.getS(receiptdata), excludeInclude: true)) { response, error in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.checkresponse(response: response as! Map)
                    }else{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }else{
                do {
                    let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)
                    let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
                    Api.inAppPurchasecall(.receiptVarify(rdata: receiptString, excludeInclude: true)) { response, error in
                        if error == nil {
                            self.checkresponse(response: response as! Map)
                        }else{
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { print("Couldn't read receipt data with error: " + error.localizedDescription) }
            }
        }else{
            requestrefreshreceipt = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()
            requestrefreshreceipt?.delegate = self
            requestrefreshreceipt?.start()
        }
    }
```

receipt response code :

```
func checkresponse(response : Map) {
        if let rdata = response["latest_receipt"] as? String {
            UD.setS(receiptdata, rdata)
        }
        if let latestreceiptinfo = response["latest_receipt_info"] as? [Map] {
            if let lastinfo = latestreceiptinfo.first {
                if let expiredate = lastinfo["expires_date"] as? String, let edate = Formatter.customDate.date(from: expiredate) {
                    if let strEdate = gmtToLocal(date: edate) {
                        self.nextBillingDate = strEdate
                    }
                }
                if let expiredate = lastinfo["purchase_date"] as? String, let edate = Formatter.customDate.date(from: expiredate) {
                    if let strEdate = gmtToLocal(date: edate) {
                        self.lastBillingDate = strEdate
                    }
                }
                if let expiretime = lastinfo["expires_date_ms"] as? String, let doubleexpiretime = Double(expiretime) {
                    expireTimeStamp = doubleexpiretime/1000
                    let currenttimestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
                    if let etimestamp = expireTimeStamp {
                        if etimestamp > currenttimestamp {
                            UD.setS(AppConst.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS, "true")
                            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: kRefreshServices), object:nil)
                        }else{
                            UD.setS(AppConst.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS, "false")
                            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: kRefreshServices), object:nil)
                            if let expiredate = lastinfo["expires_date"] as? String, let edate = Formatter.customDate.date(from: expiredate) {
                                if let root = APP_DELEGATE.window?.rootViewController {
                                    if let strEdate = gmtToLocal(date: edate) {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "after remove apple account i always get receipt response true"  Okay.  So what's the problem?  If somebody purchases a one-year subscription today and then subsequently logs out of his or her account, they aren't allowed to use the service they have paid for?

Comment: @ElTomato Thanks for replay, i just want to now, after remove apple account my application in-app purchase is worked fine or not ? if worked fine so what happened when login same account to another device ? both device in-app purchase is worked my in-app purchase time period ?